# How to loop iScroll 4 based carousel?

Tags: javascript, carousel, iscroll4

I've created a iScroll based carousel.

See fiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/r9VL2/2/

At the moment when you get to the fourth list element, it stops. Is it possible to add some code so it loops back to the first list element?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here a quick sample for the next/prev buttons of `myScroll1`. Replace their onclick with these functs:

```
function next(){
    snapNum = document.querySelectorAll('#indicator1 > li').length;
    if(myScroll1.currPageX+1 == snapNum){
        myScroll1.scrollToPage(0, 0);
    }else{
        myScroll1.scrollToPage('next', 0);
    }
}

function prev(){
    snapNum = document.querySelectorAll('#indicator1 > li').length;
    if(myScroll1.currPageX+1 == 1){
        myScroll1.scrollToPage(snapNum, 0);
    }else{
    myScroll1.scrollToPage('prev', 0);
    }
}
```

They get the length of li's to snap. Then if you are on the last, goes back to first. If you are on first, goes to last.

Of course this can be made more general and less stuff, but i'll leave to you.